# Multiple UPDATE ... FROM same row is not working

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to do multiple update, but it works only for the first row.

I have table "users" with 2 records:

```
create table users
(
  uid        serial                                 not null
    constraint users_pkey
      primary key,
  balance    numeric                  default 0     not null
);


INSERT INTO public.users (uid, balance) VALUES (2, 100);
INSERT INTO public.users (uid, balance) VALUES (1, 100);
```

I try to UPDATE user "1" twice with the query, but it update only one time:
balance for user "1" become "105", not "115"

```
update users as u
set balance = balance + c.bal
from (values (1, 5),
             (1, 10)
     ) as c(uid, bal)
where c.uid = u.uid;
```

Why it not updated for all rows from subquery?

Answer (score 1):

The postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-update.html) gives no reason for this behaviour but does specify it.

Relevant quote

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the
>   target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and
>   each output row of the join represents an update operation for the
>   target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces
>   at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a
>   target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other
>   table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to
>   update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily
>   predictable.

Use a `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` to combine the rows before performing the update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate in the inner query before joining:

```
update users as u
set balance = balance + d.bal
from ( 
  select uid, sum(bal) bal
  from ( values (1, 5), (1, 10) ) as c(uid, bal)
  group by uid
) d
where d.uid = u.uid;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJtxQpurdCrGpysB4ezYH9/0)**:

```
| uid | balance |
| --- | ------- |
| 2   | 100     |
| 1   | 115     |
```